# Polymorphism in a Cucumber-jvm Given Step

Tags: cucumber, polymorphism

I'm trying to write some steps in Cucumber-jvm and I've got a step that is approximately like
the following:

```
@Given("I am a (regular|admin|guest) user")
 public void setUser(String userType){
     if("regular".equals(userType))
         setUserType(REGULAR);
     if("admin".equals(userType))
         setUserType(ADMIN);
     if("guest".equals(userType))
         setUserType(GUEST);
}
```

Is there a better way of writing such a step, to make it polymorphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you need to have a relationship between the string and the type that it is going to set, so if you don't want a big if statmenet like that, setting up a map may be the way to go.

How about something like this....

```
public static Map<String,UserType> types = new HashMap<String,UserType>();
static {
  types.put("regular", REGULAR);
  types.put("admin", ADMIN);
  types.put("guest", GUEST);
}
```

And then

```
@Given("I am a (regular|admin|guest) user")
public void setUser(String userType){
 setUserType(types.get(userType));
}
```